# Полное и неполное предложение

Tags: синтаксис

В чём разница? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Это просто: в полном предложении заняты и представлены все компоненты его структурной схемы, поэтому мы можем понять заключённую в нём информацию, даже если вырвем предложение из контекста. В неполном же один или несколько компонентов пропущены, так что для определения его грамматического строения и семантической структуры и для восприятия заключённой в нём информации требуется конситуативная поддержка. Неполной является, к примеру, вторая реплика диалога:
*– Куда ты идёшь?

– В театр.*
В ней пропущены оба главных члена: *N1 Vf,* т.е. подлежащее и сказуемое. Смысл неполного предложения можно понять только в контексте.

Answer (score 0):

И нельзя путать с односоставными. Односоставные - полные. Так, "Вчера не учились" - полное, односоставное , неопр.-личное. А предложение "Вчера не учился", например, - двусоставное неполное.

Comment: Внесу поправку: *Вчера не учились* в зависимости от контекста, в который оно помещено, может быть реализацией структурной схемы как односоставного предложения, так и двусоставного неполного. А *Вчера не учился* – только неполного.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем просто... Когда диалог - да, неполные предложения хорошо видны. В текстах книжного стиля все сложнее. Нужны определенные знания и навык. чтобы увидеть неполное предложение.